# Question count for new and popular questions is 0

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

There aren't any new or popular questions. There are tons of questions in both of those tabs but the question count is 0 for both of those when I try to view them in the expanded view.
[image: Question Count]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had forgotten to bind the count. Thanks for noticing and reporting.

This has been fixed and the change is being deployed.